# Идентификация посетителя сайта

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. нужно написать модуль "добавить товар в избранное".

Пользователь зашел на сайт, выбрал товар, нажал добавить в избранное, товар добавился в таблицу MySQL. Но только как можно произвести идентификацию пользователя, если он не зарегистрирован и не записан ни в каких куки?

Comment: Надо куки записывать, очевидно же)

Comment: Незарегистрированные пользователи пускай у себя сами своё избранное хранят (в localstorage каком-нибудь)

Comment: `не записан ни в каких куки` А чем обусловлен отказ от cookie?

Answer (score 2):

> Но только как можно произвести идентификацию пользователя, если он не зарегистрирован и не записан ни в каких куки?

Записать его, разумеется. После того как пользователь будет идентифицирован с помощью куки, можно будет добавить его идентификатор вместе с ид товара в таблицу MySQL.

Сессии не слишком хорошо подходят для такой задачи, в силу заведомо ограниченного времени жизни.

Comment: Что будет являться идентификатором конкретного пользователя если не ID сессии и он не зарегистрирован?

Comment: Universally unique identifier

Comment: @AntonZikov произвольная строка, очевидно

Comment: @andreymal, тут могут возникнуть проблемы с уникальностью. Если я правильно понял суть UUID, то вероятно он действительно лучше подходит.

Comment: @AntonZikov и то и другое суть произвольные строки) Можно и UUID

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сессии. Даже у незарегистрированных пользователей есть идендификатор сессии, который также можно сохранить в БД если надо и использовать в качестве ключа.

Comment: Сессии используют куки, а в вопросе указано "не записан ни в каких куки"

Comment: Сессии используют куки только для хранения идентификатора. Если куки отключены, то идентификатор будет автоматически добавляться к URL. Причем все это делается автоматом без участия сторонней логики.

Comment: Оу, в 2017-м так до сих пор делают?)

Comment: А вот тут просветите меня, как пхп определит что куки отключены?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Comment: То есть никак не определит и это надо включать вручную в настройках?

Comment: Ну если есть какие-то предубеждения по поводу кук, то можно включить эту опцию и УРЛы будут подменяться в любом случае (даже если у пользователя включены куки). Причем если куки включены, то еще и туда добавит. Но я думаю - все уже давно считают транспарентные сессии извратом.

Comment: @andreymal А что, в 2017 придумали альтернативу сессиям и кукам? Не думаю, что этот механизм вообще поменяется ближайшие 10 лет.

Comment: @ilyaplot вот я ж и говорю — в вопросе написано «не записан ни в каких куки», что подразумевает отсутствие и PHPSESSID тоже, из чего (неявно) следует, что сессии для автора вопроса не годятся (если не дописывать phpsessid в url, но я ж и говорю, что в 2017-м так никто не делает)

Comment: @andreymal  `session_start()` не создает cookie.

Comment: @ilyaplot рад за него, но всё же пользователя с сессией надо как-то связать. Если url изврат, а cookie не используются, то что делать-то?

Comment: И да, мой коммент про 2017 относился к хранению сессии в url. А то подозреваю, что меня неправильно поняли

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: Возможно, это я что-то не понимаю, но когда я захожу на страницу, состоящую только из `<?php session_start(); ?>`, cookie не создаются, в URL ничего нового не появляется, а данные сессии сохраняются.

Comment: @ilyaplot, нет, такая страница создаёт cookie PHPSESSID, лично проверил прямо сейчас

Comment: Совершенно верно, кука создастся, а URL допишется только ели в php.ini включена директива session.use-trans-sid и то, если куки не поддерживаются браузером. Если PHP увидит куку с сессией, то перестанет подменять урлы и формы.

Comment: Да, наверно не совсем верно выражаюсь когда говорю URL. Имеется в виду не текущий URL (в адресной строке браузера при первом заходе ничего не поменяется), а все относительные ссылки в выводе PHP дополнит идентификатором сессии, а также добавит скрытые поля ко всем формам в выводе.